# Selenium WebDriver C# - Bypass Chrome Authentication Required dialog

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, single-sign-on, selenium-chromedriver

I have an issue with Selenium WebDriver dealing with Google Chrome Authentication dialog box. I have search the net for 2 weeks but I can't get a definite solution to it.

I have a constraint, which is Selenium WebDriver will run in a remote Windows 2012 R2 server under user SYSTEM, hence running the background **WITHOUT** Chrome UI displayed.

Due to the constraint above, AutoIT doesn't works as it requires UI to handle the events. `Driver.SwitchTo().Alert()` doesn't seem to work too as it doesn't capture the alert at all (Some said it works on IE only).

`Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://username:password@url.com")` doesn't work as well as my website is using SSO Login. It will first navigate to https://www.landingsite.com then redirected to https://authenticationrequired.com/daM2Sc, which the URL for the SSO Login is randomize every single time, so I couldn't bypass the Authentication dialog directly.

I wanted to use a workaround by capturing the authentication URL by using `Driver.Url` and the add my username and password infront of the URL, but then because of the prompted authentication dialog box, the driver fails to capture the URL and throws a timeout exception.

Some said by adding URL to trusted site would stop the dialog box being prompted but it doesn't work for some reason. It only works in IE.

Is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I lost a week to try do that, and when i can do, i think it's amazing. Java code here:
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(user:pass@URL/);
and you must encode user and pass. Link encode: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

My chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: it doesn't works for user:pass@URL since I will land at `Driver.NavigateTo.Url("www.myfirstURL.com")` then it would redirect to the authentication website, the URL is different than the 1st URL that I entered. Hence I cannot use the user:pass@URL method.

Comment: Do u encode user and pass? It require encode them to url link.